# Exception handling in EventExecutorGroup

Tags: netty

I need to create pool of threads that processes request to database (that are usually slow). I'm trying to understand example in http://adolgarev.blogspot.com/2013/12/lets-do-our-own-full-blown-http-server.html however I do not understand how exception handling is performed. What happens when Callable throws an exception.

I got a look into code of DefaultEventExecutor and DefaultEventExecutorGroup. 
As I understand from code one thread from the pool will be closed when exception from runable is thrown.

I need special handling for any exception that are thrown and no threads are closed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When the specified `Callable` throws an exception (i.e. when the `Callable` fails,) the listener you added to the `Future` returned by the `EventExecutor.submit(Callable)` will be notified (i.e. `operationComplete()` will be invoked.)  You can check if the execution of the `Callable` was successful or not via `Future.isSuccess()` or `Future.cause()`.